# Reading exact number of bytes from file after writing object to it with bincode serialisation

Tags: file, serialization, rust, io, deserialization

Im just experimenting with writing and reading objects to a file with bincode. I plan to keep pointers to different locations within the file and so I would like to be able to read up to those points with `read_exact`.

Ive written a little test to see how it would work. Creating a struct, writing it to file, getting the size of the struct and then reading precisely that many bytes.

Issue is that the size of the object returned by `std::mem::size_of` is not the same as the number of bytes written to the file.

Here is the code:

```
use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};
use std::io::prelude::*;
use bincode::*;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Node {

    pub name: String,

    end_ptr: u32 // number of bytes away the next node is
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let node = Node { name: String::from("node_1"), end_ptr: 0 };

    let node_as_buf = bincode::serialize(&node).unwrap();

    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .open("test.txt")
        .unwrap();

    file.write(&node_as_buf);

    const size_of_node: usize = std::mem::size_of::<Node>();

    println!("{}", file.metadata().unwrap().len()); //  this prints 18

    println!("{}", size_of_node); // and this prints 32, i was expecting them to be the same length

    let mut buffer = [0; size_of_node];

    file.read_exact(&mut buffer[..]).unwrap(); // this says 'failed to fill whole buffer'

    let read_node: Node = bincode::deserialize(&buffer[..]).unwrap();
}
```

What is the proper way to do this? Is there some other way to get the size of my struct?

Comment: Use `SCREAMING_CASE` for consts.

Answer (score 1):

`size_of::<Node>()` is the size an instance of `Node` occupies in the stack. It is always constant. It equals 32 since `String` is a triple `(data_ptr, length, capacity)` (not necessarily in this order) where each of the components is `usize`-sized - 8 bytes on 64 bit platforms, and one `u32` - 4 bytes - for `end_ptr`.

The size of serialized data, however, is dynamic. It depends on the serialized data, since it serializes it contiguously and does not use pointers. In this case, it is 6 bytes for the string `node_1` + a `usize` for its length + `u32` for `end_ptr`.

If you do not have the data you cannot know the serialized size. If you do have the data you can call [`bincode::serialized_size()`](https://docs.rs/bincode/latest/bincode/fn.serialized_size.html).

As a side note, do not use [`write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.write): it is not guaranteed to write all data. Use [`write_all()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.write_all) instead.

Comment: Right, that makes a lot of sense. I also realised I can just use the length of the vector that holds the bytes that the struct was serialised into. Although I still get 'failed to fill the whole buffer' even when using the length of the byte vector.